# How to determine whether the script returned exit status code 1 or 0

Tags: powershell

I am running the below PowerShell script to give Azure IAM access to a storage account

```
#Read stdin as string
$jsonpayload = [Console]::In.ReadLine()

#Convert to JSON
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonpayload

#Access JSON values
$userName = $json.userName
$resourceType = $json.resourceType
$resourceGroupName = $json.resourceGroupName

$objectid = (Get-AzureRmADUser -SearchString $userName).Id

$Result = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectid -
RoleDefinitionName Reader -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

if ($Result.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    exit 1
} else {
    # Return role result
    Write-Output '{ "roleResult" : "Role assigned successfully" }'
}
```

How to display a success message if there is no error, is there any alternate solution to handle this

I am getting the error

> command "Powershell.exe" failed with no error message

if the scripts does not throw out any error.

Comment: The statement `$Result = ...` is broken due to incorrect line-wrapping. Please post the code *exactly* as it is in your script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is broken:

> ```
> $Result = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectid -
> RoleDefinitionName Reader -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
> ```

It should look like this:

```
$Result = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectid -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

Also, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment) the `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment` returns a [`PSRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resources.models.authorization.psroleassignment) object, which doesn't have a property `ExitCode`, and you don't check the status of cmdlets like that anyway. PowerShell has a boolean [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$?` that indicates whether or not the last cmdlet call was successful or not, so your code should look like this:

```
$Result = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectid -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

if ($?) {
    # Return role result
    Write-Output '{ "roleResult" : "Role assigned successfully" }'
} else {
    exit 1
}
```